# Python - attempting to make a morse code LED

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, led, morse-code

i have attempted to write the code such that it will tell you to input your string. at which point you type a string for example lets say you type "purple" then press enter. the code will run and get the length, then instead of getting the first letter variable[0] as P and then lighting the LED in the code for P, it constantly interprets all letters as A. i know its going to be something small but ive only been learning python for a few days so try to be nice. i have previous experience with VB so i have most likely used the wrong syntax somewhere but i cant figure it out. PLEASE HELP.

i cant copy the code into this without rewriting it so im going to use screenshot links.

this is where i think the problem must be
http://puu.sh/lUf9q/3ad50c4faf.png

and then this is how i've set the morse code patterns
 http://puu.sh/lUfgo/f6f3f2cb32.png

the reason there is 2 = and 1 == is because i was tinkering with them to see if they were the problem which they aren't

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
apparently i have to edit it to say why its different to said thread. The way its different is: its not but I didn't realise that the problem in the thread was the problem i was having.

Comment: Why can't you copy paste the code?

Comment: *"i cant [sic] copy the code into this without rewriting it"* - ...then rewrite it. We want a [mcve], not a code dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interpreting all letters as "a" because your if statement says

```
if curr = "A" or "a":
```

In fact == and = *are* different. One does assignment, and the other checks for equality. This if statement always executes because there is always one side of the `or` that is true.

Try this instead

```
if curr.lower() == "a":
```

Comment: thanks. youre right that does work. i realised i used "or" incorrectly and just came back to retract/answer my own question.